# How to read txt file from FTP location in MariaDB?

Tags: file, csv, ftp, load, mariadb

I am new to MariaDB and need to do below activity.

We are using MariaDB as datatbase and we need to read a txt file from ftp location. Then load into a table. This has to be scheduled to read the file on a regular interval.

After searching I got LOAD DATA INFILE to be used, but it has the limitation that, it can't be used in Events.

Any suggestions/samples on this would be great help.

Thanks
Nitin

Answer (score 0):

You import it and read it using the local path, MariaDB does basic file support, in no case it supports FTP transactions

Answer (score 0):

`LOAD DATA` can only read a "file".  But maybe the OS can play games...

What Operating System?  If the OS can hide the fact that FTP is under the covers, then `LOAD DATA` will be none the wiser.